# Use "require" in sails js app

Tags: javascript, sails.js

When [disabling globals](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-globals) the docs suggests using the following alternatives:

- _ = require('lodash')
- myService = sails.services.myservice
- myModel = sails.models.mymodel
- sails = req._sails

Would there be any issue requiring "sails", "services", and "models" much like any other module?

Having tried It, it does appear to work, however I feel I might be missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `require` for services is always valid; the globalizing is merely for convenience.

On the other hand, doing `require('api/models/User.js')` will almost certainly *not* give you what you want, since those files are used by Sails to build model classes.  So the only way to reliably use models in Sails without globals turned on is via `sails.models`.

Finally, while `require('sails')` will usually give you a reference to the running Sails app, it's not recommended that you use it that way.  If you were running multiple Sails apps in the same process (which you might do in automated tests) then it would not reliably return the correct app.  You're much better off using `req._sails` in controllers, and `this.sails` in models and services.

---

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The docs don't appear to mention accessing sails via "this.sails" for models and services. Should passing a reference from the controller be prefered? e.g. inside a controller action call myService.someMethod(req._sails)

Comment: That's a perfectly valid way of doing it, but `this.sails` is definitely safe.  Re: documentation, good call, will look into that.